# How to create custom options with bootstrap combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I made a form and it types ahead every option perfectly. My question is how can I make the drop down items with an icon to the left of the text and link when clicked on one rather then just the text show? Like for example i want an icon next to alabama when it shows up when i type "a" and when i click it i want it to go to a certain page.

```
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="combobox form-control" name="inline">
      <option value="" selected="selected">select a state</option>
        <option value="AL">alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">arkansas</option>
         <option value="AZ">arizona</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

my java script

```
 <script type"text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.combobox').combobox() });
 </script>
```

its is bootstrap-combobox.js

Comment: Please do not re-post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
<option value="AL">alabama <a href="myUrl"><img src="myImage" /></a></option>
```

Comment: yes, when i click alabama it just fills the text box and no icon appears.